# Custom rotator control WAGG2.0 AA validation

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, slideshow, wcag2.0

First of all sorry about my english, sure Shakespeare must be turning in his grave.

Very simple question I've got a custom image rotator control inside my master page with a div and appling some javasript that uses slideshow method and I need my page to pass WCAG AA validation.

Is mandatory my control has buttons in order to stop and start the animation and pass WCAG2.0 AA validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about meeting [WCAG standards with carousels on W3.org](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/carousels/), but to answer your question, yes you must have controls to pause/stop and play your carousel, assuming that functionality is present. You can avoid this requirement by not allowing the carousel to automatically loop through the slides and instead restrict the looping of the slides to a "previous" and "next" arrow (button) that would advance the slides one at a time.